# Use of ..col in a j expression in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm having trouble getting the desired behavior from the `..j` syntax in the latest version of `data.table`, when I want to query a column using a variable in the column scope, and then *manipulate that variable*. By way of example, here is a table:

```
A <- data.table(myValA = c(6,23,7,2,5), myValB = c(43,12,7,89,2))
valA <- "myValA"
valB <- "myValB"
```

I want to get the element by element product of the two columns:

```
A[, myValA * myValB]

[1] 258 276  49 178  10
```

But I want to call the columns by reference, using variables in the calling scope, `valA` and `valB`. To simply access the variables, the `..valA` syntax works fine.

```
A[, ..valA]

   myValA
1:      6
2:     23
3:      7
4:      2
5:      5
```

and similarly for `..valB`. But when I try to multiply the two columns in `j`, using either the old `with=False` style or the new `..j` style command, I get errors:

```
A[, ..valA * ..valB]
Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object '..valA' not found

A[, valA * valB, with = FALSE]
Error in valA * valB : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

I have a handle on some appropriate ways to solve this problem (cheers to akrun below), but I'm also trying to understand more about why this doesn't work in the first place. Nothing in my understanding of the syntax, at least, leads me to a clear reason why it should not.

Comment: Currently the `..` syntax is not very well documented in the help text. However, I believe you basically can read about the `with` argument in `?data.table`, i.e. the part that starts with "When `with=FALSE`", and think "when using `..col`". If so: "When [using `..col`, ] `j` [_should be_] a character vector of column names, a numeric vector of column positions to select or of the form startcol:endcol.". Thus, the column(s) specified in `..col` can only be used for _selecting_ columns. Also note the last 'Note': `x[, cols, with=FALSE]` is equivalent to `x[, .SD, .SDcols=cols]`, which explains

Comment: ...why @akrun's first solution works.

Comment: If you abuse `j` in other ways, you may provoke an informative error message related to `with = FALSE` and its 'select only' functionality: `A[ , .(val = valA), with = FALSE]`; `Error in `[.data.table`(A, , .(val = valA), with = FALSE) : 
  When with=FALSE, j-argument should be of type logical/character/integer indicating the columns to select`. And this seems to apply to `..col` as well

Comment: They considered your desired usage back in 2014, I think: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/697#issuecomment-46305236 Not sure if it's still being considered.

Comment: FYI: some days ago, I posted [an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2145), asking for some more documentation on `..col`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify in the `.SDcols` and then do the elementwise multiplication using `Reduce`

```
A[, Reduce(`*`, .SD), .SDcols = c(valA, valB)]
#[1] 258 276  49 178  10
```

---

Or instead of having two objects, create a single object

```
v1 <- c(valA, valB)
A[,  ..v1][, do.call(`*`, .SD)]
#[1] 258 276  49 178  10
```

---

Or we can evaluate it separately and multiply

```
(A[, ..valA] * A[, ..valB])[[1]]
#[1] 258 276  49 178  10
```

Comment: So, these all solve the problem as posed (my actual code involves a join, where `myValA` and `myValB` come from different tables `A` and `B`, so the `Reduce()` solution doesn't work, but the other two work fine), but I guess I'm also trying to understand the logic of why `..valA * ..valB` doesn't work. From my intuitive (but limited) understanding of the idea behind the `..j` syntax, it isn't clear to me why it *shouldn't* work.

Comment: @ConnorJ Or another option is `A[, Reduce("*", mget(c(valA, valB)))]`  I think it has to do with the evaluation and the operator precedence